# Syntax error in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have code:

```
DATE=$(date --utc "+%FT%T.%N" | sed -r 's/[[:digit:]]{6}$/Z/');
JOBS_ID="\"56449e75e4b01da8ea330b9d\", \"56449e75e4b01da8ea330b68\", \"56449e75e4b01da8ea330b60\", \"56449e75e4b01da8ea330b53\", \"56449e75e4b01da8ea330b55\", \"56449e74e4b01da8ea330b2e\", \"56449e77e4b01da8ea330cac\""   
declare -a arr=($JOBS_ID)
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
id=$( echo "$i" | tr -d , )
echo "Force a cease of RP launch, ID=$id"
curl --user user:pass -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: */*" -d "{ 
\"end_time\":\"$DATE\", 
\"status\": \"passed\" 
}" "https://<some_rest_resource>/api/v1/my_project/launch/$id/finish"
done
```

I constantly got exception on my jenkins build log:

> + date --utc +%FT%T.%N+  sed -r s/[[:digit:]]{6}$/Z/
>   + DATE=2015-11-13T13:58:51.162Z /tmp/hudson1799790879869363544.sh: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected Build step 'Execute shell' marked build
>   as failure

Online syntax checkers say that everything fine. Please, help me with finding a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are a new kid in a shell scripting. 
You have to indicate standardization, fellow:

```
#!/bin/bash
```